# Android DataBinding in multiple module Type com.xxx.xxxx.databinding.xxxxxBinding is defined multiple times

Tags: android, android-databinding

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Type com.iwhalecloud.tt.databinding.FragmentFaqDetailBinding is defined multiple times: D:\code\mobilesc-android-sdec-new\app\build\intermediates\mixed_scope_dex_archive\originRelease\out\com\iwhalecloud\tt\databinding\FragmentFaqDetailBinding.dex, D:\code\mobilesc-android-sdec-new\app\build\intermediates\mixed_scope_dex_archive\originRelease\out\3f3568e596d93f44a6b8275444e7e93403954827ce5becbe5c2f0a126ca13e39_2.jar:classes.dex","sources":[{"file":"D:\code\mobilesc-android-sdec-new\app\build\intermediates\mixed_scope_dex_archive\originRelease\out\com\iwhalecloud\tt\databinding\FragmentFaqDetailBinding.dex"}],"tool":"D8"}
com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:
Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
Type com.iwhalecloud.tt.databinding.FragmentFaqDetailBinding is defined multiple times: D:\code\mobilesc-android-sdec-new\app\build\intermediates\mixed_scope_dex_archive\originRelease\out\com\iwhalecloud\tt\databinding\FragmentFaqDetailBinding.dex, D:\code\mobilesc-android-sdec-new\app\build\intermediates\mixed_scope_dex_archive\originRelease\out\3f3568e596d93f44a6b8275444e7e93403954827ce5becbe5c2f0a126ca13e39_2.jar:classes.dex
at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.getExceptionToRethrow(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:151)
at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:138)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingWorkAction.merge(DexMergingTask.kt:859)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingWorkAction.run(DexMergingTask.kt:805)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.profile.ProfileAwareWorkAction.execute(ProfileAwareWorkAction.kt:74)
at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerServer.execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:63)
at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:66)
at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:62)
at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.executeInClassloader(ClassLoaderUtils.java:100)
at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.lambda$execute$0(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:62)
at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:44)
at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:41)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker.executeWrappedInBuildOperation(AbstractWorker.java:41)
at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.execute(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:59)
at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor.lambda$submitWork$2(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:205)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runExecution(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:187)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.access$700(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:120)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner$1.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:162)
at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:31)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:249)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:109)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:114)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runBatch(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:157)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:126)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete, origin: D:\code\mobilesc-android-sdec-new\app\build\intermediates\mixed_scope_dex_archive\originRelease\out\com\iwhalecloud\tt\databinding\FragmentFaqDetailBinding.dex
at Version.fakeStackEntry(Version_3.2.60.java:0)
at com.android.tools.r8.internal.bi.a(R8_3.2.60_61a204e00a4460bee78ec2913234dc5e1a3a501d9754e757835d117b7e302ba3:68)
at com.android.tools.r8.internal.bi.a(R8_3.2.60_61a204e00a4460bee78ec2913234dc5e1a3a501d9754e757835d117b7e302ba3:28)
at com.android.tools.r8.internal.bi.a(R8_3.2.60_61a204e00a4460bee78ec2913234dc5e1a3a501d9754e757835d117b7e302ba3:27)
at com.android.tools.r8.internal.bi.b(R8_3.2.60_61a204e00a4460bee78ec2913234dc5e1a3a501d9754e757835d117b7e302ba3:3)
at com.android.tools.r8.D8.run(R8_3.2.60_61a204e00a4460bee78ec2913234dc5e1a3a501d9754e757835d117b7e302ba3:11)
at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:136)
... 38 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.internal.a: Type com.iwhalecloud.tt.databinding.FragmentFaqDetailBinding is defined multiple times: D:\code\mobilesc-android-sdec-new\app\build\intermediates\mixed_scope_dex_archive\originRelease\out\com\iwhalecloud\tt\databinding\FragmentFaqDetailBinding.dex, D:\code\mobilesc-android-sdec-new\app\build\intermediates\mixed_scope_dex_archive\originRelease\out\3f3568e596d93f44a6b8275444e7e93403954827ce5becbe5c2f0a126ca13e39_2.jar:classes.dex
at com.android.tools.r8.internal.uQ.a(R8_3.2.60_61a204e00a4460bee78ec2913234dc5e1a3a501d9754e757835d117b7e302ba3:14)
at com.android.tools.r8.internal.uQ.a(R8_3.2.60_61a204e00a4460bee78ec2913234dc5e1a3a501d9754e757835d117b7e302ba3:22)
at com.android.tools.r8.internal.yK.b(R8_3.2.60_61a204e00a4460bee78ec2913234dc5e1a3a501d9754e757835d117b7e302ba3:7)
at com.android.tools.r8.internal.yK.a(R8_3.2.60_61a204e00a4460bee78ec2913234dc5e1a3a501d9754e757835d117b7e302ba3:23)
at com.android.tools.r8.internal.yK.a(R8_3.2.60_61a204e00a4460bee78ec2913234dc5e1a3a501d9754e757835d117b7e302ba3:10)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.merge(ConcurrentHashMap.java:2056)
at com.android.tools.r8.internal.yK.a(R8_3.2.60_61a204e00a4460bee78ec2913234dc5e1a3a501d9754e757835d117b7e302ba3:6)
at com.android.tools.r8.graph.A2$a.e(R8_3.2.60_61a204e00a4460bee78ec2913234dc5e1a3a501d9754e757835d117b7e302ba3:4)
at com.android.tools.r8.dex.b.a(R8_3.2.60_61a204e00a4460bee78ec2913234dc5e1a3a501d9754e757835d117b7e302ba3:105)
at com.android.tools.r8.dex.b.a(R8_3.2.60_61a204e00a4460bee78ec2913234dc5e1a3a501d9754e757835d117b7e302ba3:28)
at com.android.tools.r8.D8.a(R8_3.2.60_61a204e00a4460bee78ec2913234dc5e1a3a501d9754e757835d117b7e302ba3:26)
at com.android.tools.r8.D8.d(R8_3.2.60_61a204e00a4460bee78ec2913234dc5e1a3a501d9754e757835d117b7e302ba3:593)
at com.android.tools.r8.D8.b(R8_3.2.60_61a204e00a4460bee78ec2913234dc5e1a3a501d9754e757835d117b7e302ba3:1)
at com.android.tools.r8.internal.bi.a(R8_3.2.60_61a204e00a4460bee78ec2913234dc5e1a3a501d9754e757835d117b7e302ba3:24)
... 41 more

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

my  project has multiple module  , i use a same  name  layout .xml in app moudle，i think i can merge  xml， debug is ok .when i  generate release apk/aab it not work. sub moudle is common  use maven,app moudle custom some ui

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.